# How to set the "phonograph2:write-table-edits-on-behalf-of" property on a foundry dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

I want to write into a phonograph index and like to use the "onBehalfOf" property in the PostEvent. But I have no idea how to set this property. The API tells me "The `phonograph2:write-table-edits-on-behalf-of` operation is required on the writeback dataset RID associated with the given table if this field is specified"
But how to do this?

I searched the API doc but found nothing